# How to use MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly instead of MetadataFileReference

Tags: c#, .net

I downloaded package **C# Code Rendering with Roslyn** from NuGet by **Richard Bayler Levaro**.

This package compiles and runs fine with Visual Studio CTP6. When I upgraded references to **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis** to the latest version I discovered that the following fails to compile as **MetaFileReferences** seems to have gone.

Richard has the following code to create a collection of Referenced Assemblies in the Project in which the source code will be parsed (I think). Here is his code:

> ```
> Assembly csharpDisplay = typeof(CodeWalker).Assembly;
> renderer.MetadataReferences.Add(
>                            new MetadataFileReference(assembly.Location));
>
> csharpDisplay.GetReferencedAssemblies()
>     .ToList()
>     .ForEach(a => renderer.MetadataReferences.Add(
>     new MetadataFileReference(Assembly.Load(a).Location)));
> ```

He then uses the list of referenced assemblies to create **CSharpCompilation** as below:

```
 Compilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("CoreRenderer",
                syntaxTrees: new List<SyntaxTree> { SyntaxTree },
               references: MetadataReferences);

 SemanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(SyntaxTree);
```

My research suggests that I need to amend the above to use **MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly**. But I don't know how. How do I rewrite above code?

Also CSharpKind property seems to have gone for a SyntaxNode!!

Answer (score 1):

I contacted **Richard Bayler Levaro** and he provided the answer below:

```
        Assembly csharpDisplay = typeof(CodeWalker).Assembly;
        renderer.MetadataReferences.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(assembly));     
        csharpDisplay.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                     .ToList()
                     .ForEach(a => renderer.MetadataReferences.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(Assembly.Load(a))));
```